# Why are the following objects numpy strings instead of datetime.datetime objects?

Tags: python, date, csv, numpy

I have a csv file arranged as follows:

```
Person,Date1,Date2,Status
Person1,12/10/11,17/10/11,Done
...
```

I want to perform various operations on it and I'm starting by pulling it into Python and converting the date strings to datetime.datetime objects. I have the following code:

```
import re
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil import rrule

def get_data(csv_file = '/home/garry/Desktop/complaints/input.csv'):
    inp = np.genfromtxt(csv_file,
        delimiter=',',
        filling_values = None,
        dtype = None)

    date = re.compile(r'\d+/\d+/\d+')
    count = 0
    item_count = 0

    for line in inp:
        for item in line:
            if re.match(date, item):
                item = datetime.strptime(item, '%d/%m/%y')
                inp[count][item_count] = item
                item_count += 1
            else:
                item_count += 1
        item_count = 0
        count += 1

    return inp

def get_teams(data):
    team_list = []
    for line in data:
        if line[0] not in team_list:
            team_list.append(line[0])
        else:
            pass
    del team_list[0]
    return team_list

def get_months():
    month_list = []
    months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
    now = datetime.now()
    start_month = now.month - 7
    for count in range(0,7):
        if months[start_month] > now.month:
            year = now.year - 1
        else:
            year = now.year
        month_list.append([months[start_month], year])
        start_month += 1
    return month_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inp = get_data()
    for item in inp[2]:
        print type(item)
    team_list = get_teams(inp)
    month_list = get_months()
```

The print statement in the main method (inserted for debugging) returns:

```
<type 'numpy.string_'>
<type 'numpy.string_'>
<type 'numpy.string_'>
<type 'numpy.string_'>
```

which is obviously not what I'm hoping for, since the loop in the get_data() function is supposed to change the date strings to datetime.datetime objects. When I run the same code as is in the loop on individual date strings as a test they convert the Type just fine. In the code above they are also working in one sense because the strings do change to the datetime.datetime format - they just aren't the right Type. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `inp` array you define in `get_data` gets a `"|S8` dtype from `np.genfromtxt`. If you try to replace one of its elements by another object, the object is transformed into a string.

A first idea would be to transform `inp` into a list, with `inp.tolist()`. That way, you can change the type of each individual field as you see fit. But there's better (I think):

According to your example, the second and third columns are always dates, right ? Then, you could convert the strings to `datetime` objects straight away with `np.genfromtxt`

```
np.genfromtxt(csv_file,
              delimiter=",",
              dtype=None,
              names=True,
              converters={1:lambda d:datetime.strptime(d,"%d/%m/%y"),
                          2:lambda d:datetime.strptime(d,"%d/%m/%y")})
```

The `names=True` means that you'll get a structured `ndarray` as output, with the fields taken from the very first non-commented line (here, your `Person,Date1,Date2,Status`). The `converters` keyword, as you guessed it, will convert the strings from the 2nd and 3rd column to `datetime` objects.

Note that if you already know that your first and last column are strings, you may want to use  another `dtype` than None: `np.genfromtxt` works faster if it doesn't have to guess the types of each column.

Now, for another comment:

- instead of keeping a counter in your `for` loop, use something like `for (i, item) in enumerate(whatever)`, it's simpler.

Comment: Let me stress again that unless you have absolutely no idea about the structure of your data, you shouldn't use `dtype=None` in `np.genfromtxt`. Here, you should use `dtype=("|S8",object,object,"|S8")` (or whatever the size of your strings).

Comment: Thanks Pierre, already taken on board in my script's next iteration.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the type of numpy arrays is fixed. Numpy stores data in a fixed-size contiguous block of memory, so when you assign a value to an index in a `numpy` array, `numpy` converts it before storing it in the array. It does this even with arrays of strings. For example:

```
>>> a = numpy.array(['xxxxxxxxxx'] * 10)
>>> for index, datum in enumerate(a):
...     print datum, a[index], type(a[index])
...     a[index] = 5
...     print datum, a[index], type(a[index])
... 
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx <type 'numpy.string_'>
xxxxxxxxxx 5 <type 'numpy.string_'>
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx <type 'numpy.string_'>
xxxxxxxxxx 5 <type 'numpy.string_'>
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx <type 'numpy.string_'>
xxxxxxxxxx 5 <type 'numpy.string_'>
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx <type 'numpy.string_'>
xxxxxxxxxx 5 <type 'numpy.string_'>
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx <type 'numpy.string_'>
xxxxxxxxxx 5 <type 'numpy.string_'>
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx <type 'numpy.string_'>
xxxxxxxxxx 5 <type 'numpy.string_'>
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx <type 'numpy.string_'>
xxxxxxxxxx 5 <type 'numpy.string_'>
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx <type 'numpy.string_'>
xxxxxxxxxx 5 <type 'numpy.string_'>
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx <type 'numpy.string_'>
xxxxxxxxxx 5 <type 'numpy.string_'>
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx <type 'numpy.string_'>
xxxxxxxxxx 5 <type 'numpy.string_'>
```

Conveniently (or not!) `datetime.datetime` objects can be converted using `str`, so in this line...

```
inp[count][item_count] = item
```

...`numpy` simply converts the item to a string and inserts that into the array.

Now, you *could* skirt this behavior by using `dtype=object`. But doing so negates much of the speed of `numpy`, because you're forcing `numpy` to call a bunch of slow python code.

```
>>> a = numpy.array(['xxxxxxxxxx'] * 10, dtype=object)
>>> for index, datum in enumerate(a):
...     print datum, a[index], type(a[index])
...     a[index] = 5
...     print datum, a[index], type(a[index])
... 
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx <type 'str'>
xxxxxxxxxx 5 <type 'int'>
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx <type 'str'>
xxxxxxxxxx 5 <type 'int'>
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx <type 'str'>
xxxxxxxxxx 5 <type 'int'>
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx <type 'str'>
xxxxxxxxxx 5 <type 'int'>
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx <type 'str'>
xxxxxxxxxx 5 <type 'int'>
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx <type 'str'>
xxxxxxxxxx 5 <type 'int'>
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx <type 'str'>
xxxxxxxxxx 5 <type 'int'>
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx <type 'str'>
xxxxxxxxxx 5 <type 'int'>
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx <type 'str'>
xxxxxxxxxx 5 <type 'int'>
xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx <type 'str'>
xxxxxxxxxx 5 <type 'int'>
```

I'll add that you're not using `numpy` to its full potential here. Numpy is designed to work on arrays in a vectorized way, without explicit `for` loops. (See the [tutorial](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html) for more on that.) So whenever you use a `for` loop to work with `numpy`, it's natural to ask how you might avoid doing so. Rather than pointing out the problems with your code, I'll show you one interesting thing you can do:

```
>>> numpy.genfromtxt('input.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True)
array([('Person1', '12/10/11', '17/10/11', 'Done'),
       ('Person1', '12/10/11', '17/10/11', 'Done'),
       ('Person1', '12/10/11', '17/10/11', 'Done'),
       ('Person1', '12/10/11', '17/10/11', 'Done'),
       ('Person1', '12/10/11', '17/10/11', 'Done'),
       ('Person1', '12/10/11', '17/10/11', 'Done')], 
      dtype=[('Person', '|S7'), ('Date1', '|S8'), 
             ('Date2', '|S8'), ('Status', '|S4')])
>>> a = numpy.genfromtxt('input.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True)
>>> a['Status']
array(['Done', 'Done', 'Done', 'Done', 'Done', 'Done'], 
      dtype='|S4')
>>> a['Date1']
array(['12/10/11', '12/10/11', '12/10/11', '12/10/11', '12/10/11',
       '12/10/11'], 
      dtype='|S8')
```

Now instead of looping over the table with a regular expression, you can simply access the dates directly.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and effort to answer so thoroughly. I've accepted Pierre GM's answer as closer to what I needed but this was extremely helpful and I'm putting time aside tomorrow to understand it more fully. Upvoted.